# Check all checkboxes in a listview

Tags: vb.net

I want to have a button that will check all checkboxes in my listview. I have:

```
Dim I as Integer
If listViewAccounts.CheckedItems.Count > 0 then

   (>>My Problem here<<)

End if
```

What to do next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i = 0 to listViewAccounts.Items.Count -1
   listViewAccounts.Items(i).Checked = true
next
```

Comment: Change `Items[i]` to `Items(i)` and I'll give you an up-vote;)

Comment: doesn't seem to work. i changed it. but then. nothing happened

Comment: Corrected! Leo, you sure that doesn't work? Try putting just the code above in a button, and click the button. All items should be checked. Are you sure you have check boxes enabled on the listview. Is the listview in details mode?

Comment: @JonBarker Top! +1 ;)

Comment: It's working now, the problem was, i inserted your code in between my code above.

Comment: @LeoElvinLee I saw someone posted (and withdrew) a LINQ solution which obviously didn't work. Here's a solution which _do_ works: `Array.ForEach(Of ListViewItem)(listViewAccounts.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).ToArray(), Sub(item As ListViewItem) item.Checked = True)`

Answer (score 7):

Or just use Linq

```
listView1.Items.OfType(Of ListViewItem).All(Function(c)
                                              c.Checked = True
                                              Return True
                                            End Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In listViewAccounts.Items
    lvi.Checked = True
Next
```